# How to display the data extracted from XML to be displayed in Yii Cgridview

Tags: php, yii

I'm trying to extract a data from XML and display it in Yii Cgridview. Below is the XML

```
<tolist>
</tolist>
<cclist>
  <cc>
  <contactpersonname>niraj</contactpersonname>
  <name>niraj</name>
  <email>stgh@gmail.com</email>
  <number>+91.3212365212</number>
  <prefix>Ms.</prefix>
  <contactpersonprefix>Ms.</contactpersonprefix>
</cc>
<cc>
```

Here I want to show only `contactpersonname` and `email`.
I tried the following

```
array(
  'name' => 'Address', 
  'value'=> function($data) {
     //print_r($data->Address);
     $xml_response = new SimpleXMLElement($data->Address);
     $email=$xml_response->email;
     print_r($email);
  },
),
```

`$data->Address` contains the above XML
But, this is not working. How to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert xml into php object as below

```
     $xml =   '<cc>
            <contactpersonname>niraj</contactpersonname>
           <name>niraj</name>
        <email>stgh@gmail.com</email>
        <number>+91.3212365212</number>
        <prefix>Ms.</prefix>
        <contactpersonprefix>Ms.</contactpersonprefix>
        </cc>';

       $xml_object = simplexml_load_string($xml );//this function convert xml into php object




        echo       $xml_object->contactpersonname ;

        echo       $xml_object->email;
```

It worked for me